# ¿Cómo valido fechas con expresiones regulares en Bash?

Tags: regex, date, bash

dejo mi script para que me ayuden a entender dónde está el error y poder corregirlo:

```
#!/bin/bash
fechaDeNacimientoRegex='^19|20[0-9]{2}[1-12]{2}[1-31]$'
#Validacion y entrada de la fecha
read -p "Por favor ingresa la fecha formato [yyyyMMdd]:
" fechaNacimiento
if [[ $fechaNacimiento =~ $fechaDeNacimientoRegex ]]; then
    echo "La fecha $fechaNacimiento es valida"
else  
    echo "La fecha $fechaNacimiento es invalida"
fi
```

El output cuando ingreso una fecha entre 1900 y 1999 funciona:

```
Por favor ingresa la fecha formato [yyyyMMdd]:
19921129
La fecha 19921129 es valida
```

Pero no funciona cuando pongo 2000 o mayor:

```
 Por favor ingresa la fecha formato [yyyyMMdd]:
 20110330
 La fecha 20110330 es invalida
```

Comment: Hola. ¿Qué necesitas? ¿Qué valide solamente fechas igual o mayor a 2000/01/01?

Comment: ¿Seguro que tus rangos están bien? No sé en bash, pero en otros lenguajes poner `[1-12]{2}` solo te aceptaría los números 11 y 12.

Comment: así como está, le estás diciendo `X|Y`, es decir, que o bien sea X o bien Y. E X está definida como solamente "19". Por tanto, la única fecha que da por buena que empieza por 19... es exactamente "19". La clave de usar paréntesis: `(X|Y)blabla` busca todo aquello que tiene o bien X, o bien Y, seguido de "blabla".

Comment: Si quieres comentar algo en las respuestas, hazlo en comentarios :) Si es relevante para la pregunta, dale a [edit] para editarla y poner más detalles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Como decía en un comentario, la expresión regular está mal. No puedes decir que quieres números entre 1 y 12 sin más, puedes decir qué caracteres aceptar y en qué orden.

Tengo una expresión regular, bastante más larga, pero que parece funcionar para lo que deseas:

```
^(19[0-9]{2}|20[0-9]{2})(0[1-9]|10|11|12)(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1])$
```

Por partes:

- Año: `(19[0-9]{2}|20[0-9]{2})` es parecido a lo que tienes, pero entre paréntesis para capturarlo.
- Mes: `(0[1-9]|10|11|12)` quiere decir un 0 seguido de un número entre 1 y 9, o un 10, o un 11, o un 12. Entre paréntesis para capturar el resultado.
- Día: `(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1])` quiere decir un 0 seguido de un número entre 1 y 9, o un 1 seguido de un número entre 0 y 9, o un 2 seguido de un número entre 0 y 9, o un 3 seguido de un 0 o 1. Entre paréntesis para capturar el resultado.

Gracias a que capturamos el resultado, podemos hacer:

```sh
fechaDeNacimientoRegex='^(19[0-9]{2}|20[0-9]{2})(0[1-9]|10|11|12)(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1])$'
read -p "Por favor ingresa la fecha formato [yyyyMMdd]:
" fechaNacimiento
if [[ $fechaNacimiento =~ $fechaDeNacimientoRegex ]]; then
    anio=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    mes=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
    dia=${BASH_REMATCH[3]}
    echo "Año: $anio"
    echo "Mes: $mes"
    echo "Día: $dia"
fi
```

Ahora, las variables `$anio`, `$mes` y `$dia` contienen la parte que encaja con la expresión regular, y puedes hacer más validaciones, como por ejemplo, que febrero no acepte más de 29 días, o indicar qué número es el que hace la fecha inválida:

```sh
if [ "$mes" -gt "12" ]; then
    echo "El mes $mes es invalido"
elif [ "$dia" -gt "31" ]; then
    echo "El dia $dia es invalido"
else
    echo "La fecha $fechaNacimiento es valida"
fi
```

Comment: Mejoro, pero no funciona para fechas en el rango 1900 a 1999, ¿ sabes por que ?

Comment: Ah, creo que `(19|20[0-9]{2})` tiene que ser `(19[0-9]{2}|20[0-9]{2})`, he editado mi respuesta

Comment: Funciono perfecto gracias por compartir tus conocimientos.  
pdta: Puedes volver a editar para quitar el parentesis extra en la parte de la viñeta **Mes**.

Comment: respuesta correcta en cuanto al uso de expresión regular. Ahora bien, creo más recomendable usar `date` que ya hace la validación de la fecha. No hay necesidad de reinventar la rueda :)

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' sí, no conocía tu solución, pero es la que usaría.

Comment: @ArianJM si se me permite la nota histórica: hace un montón de años publiqué en Stack Overflow una [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21112809/1983854) en el que sugería algo parecido a lo tuyo para validar fechas. Pues bien, como ha cogido muchas visitas, es bastante leída y a lo largo del tiempo me han comentado taaantas veces que es mejor usar `date` que ahora soy yo el pesado diciéndolo :P En cualquier caso, gran respuesta la tuya, el uso de BASH_REMATCH es un gran desconocido que permite grandes cosas para casos así.

Answer (score 6):

Si quieres validar una fecha, qué mejor que usar `date` mismo para que la valide. Si se la pasas con `date -d "$fecha"`, el código de salida te dirá si es buena o no:

```
if date -d "$fecha" &>/dev/null; then
    echo "fecha válida"
else
    echo "fecha NO válida"
fi
```

Veámoslo con un par de ejemplos:

```
$ for f in 20211231 19001300; do if date -d "$f" &>/dev/null; then echo "fecha $f válida"; else echo "fecha $f NO válida"; fi; done
fecha 20211231 válida
fecha 19001300 NO válida
```

Comment: El problema con eso es que si tengo un formato de Horas, minutos, segundos, entraria como fecha valida algo como `23:09:43` cuando lo que queria en ese entonces era unica y exclusivamente validar año, mes, dia.

Comment: Fedorqui pana en ese entonces yo estaba aprendiendo regex y tenia como ejercicio validar fechas con regex pero ahora me encuentro con que necesito validar tiempo sin regex y probando tu respuesta cai en cuenta.

Comment: ¿conoces algún truco con date para validar un formato especifico?

Comment: @AgileSoul no es que no deje mencionar, es que si escribes al autor de la publicación, te elimina el nombre automáticamente porque es redundante: [¿Cómo funcionan las @ respuestas en los comentarios?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1357/83)

Comment: Sobre _¿conoces algún truco con date para validar un formato especifico?_, dame @AgileSoul algún ejemplo específico.

Comment: Si estoy pidiendo como entrada una fecha de nacimiento, al validarla con `date -d $fechaNacimiento` retornara **true** aunque `fechaNacimeinto=23:09:43`, y eso seria un error puesto que **no** quiero que me ***acepte horas, minutos y segundos***, yo solo quiero que me valide ***año, mes, dia***.

Comment: @AgileSoul pues entonces deberías ir a las expresiones regulares, pues tu funcionalidad define como inválido cosas que `date` sí da por buenas

Answer (score 0):

Suena a que esa expresión regular sería extremadamente verbosa.

Te propongo una alternativa con una regex tipo *perl* y `grep`:

```
$ grep -P '^(19|20)\d{2}\d{2}\d{2}$' <<< "19921129" && echo valida || echo 
invalida
19921129
valida
```

Ahora con una inválida:

```
$ grep -P '^(19|20)\d{2}\d{2}\d{2}$' <<< "1992119" && echo valida || echo invalida
invalida
```

Usado en tu código, quedaría algo así:

```sh
#Validacion y entrada de la fecha

read -p "Por favor ingresa la fecha formato [yyyyMMdd]:" fechaNacimiento

if grep -qP '^(19|20)\d{2}\d{2}\d{2}$' <<< "$fechaNacimiento"; then
    echo "La fecha $fechaNacimiento es valida"
else  
    echo "La fecha $fechaNacimiento es invalida"
fi
```

Tambien podrías hacer un análisis por número. Es decir, por los primeros cuatro números que estén entre "1900" y "2099". Y los siguientes que pertenezcan a una expresión regular.